# Is rank still a good indicator of personal skill with the new Dynamic Queue?

Tags: league-of-legends

Riot recently implemented the new ranked system, the so-called dynamic queue. They removed the solo/duo queue and it is not possible for the player to choose between those. In the dynamic queue you are able to team up with more than 2 people and play with them ranked.

In season 5 one could actually be sure that if you saw a player being Diamond 1, he would play like Diamond 1. You could actually judge someone by his division and it was always pretty accurate.

I'm under the impression that Elo and LP are just numbers now and don't represent how good you actually are as an individual anymore. You could simply be carried by a bunch of players you just queue up with.

Is this assumption correct or am I totally wrong?

Comment: I used to play with a silver 5 while I am a plat 2. The enemy team often consisted of players of my level, AKA high plat and low diamonds and I doubt riot changed that. Meaning you will play against opponents equal to the most skilled member in a party. But that is from experience, I could be wrong.

Comment: @Bl00dylicious What I mean is, you can now queue up with your master friends, while you just might be platinum and they carry you to diamond..

Comment: @Bl00dylicious I always assumed it to be an average of your composition i.e. me being silver and my friend being high gold resulted in a low gold opposition.

Comment: I don't think he's asking about **who** you can queue with, but rather, whether or not personal skill matters as a result of being able to bring as many teammates as you can with you.

Comment: @nukeforum as in how much of an impact can one persons skill level make in a team overall? Or does he perhaps mean, is there only one metric for gauging skill now a 'rank' rather than both a team rank and personal rank?

Comment: @nickson104 I'm just making assumptions based on what is written in the question. Maybe it needs to be clarified further. I assume that they're asking if your rank actually says anything about your personal skill anymore since you can queue with as many people as you want. **Edit**: Holy heck, I nailed it!

Comment: @nukeforum yes you nailed it :)

Comment: @IbrahimApachi I just submitted a really big edit, feel free to reject it if you don't feel like it represents your question.

Comment: In my opinion in any kind of online game where You play as part of the team rank system will never show 100 % true. In lol is same. Some one can be in D1 but play like B5 because he bought acc. And in other way someone can be in B but play like G or P. New system look nice but skill depend on to many thinks like connection or simply how tired is player e.g. Rank system can whisper how can someone play but don't treat is as 100 % info

Comment: @Aht of course some one might be boosted or some one had a lucky win streak but if you do the maths and play a lot of games your placement is accurate. It is no coincidence that challenger players always end up in challenger with their accs and bronze scrubs end up in bronze...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like 5v5 ranked team queue before it, playing with people you know doesn't necessarily guarantee you a win. That is, if you're making the assumption that all individuals are equal at your rank.

The teamwork factor can make a huge difference, but if you're playing against individuals who are objectively better than each one of your teammates, more often than not, this will result in a loss for you.

**Edit**: Concerning the content of the edited question: yes, there may be some inflation of rank, however, you must keep in mind that Riot restricts the rank gap of players queuing ranked together.

https://support.riotgames.com/hc/en-us/articles/204010760-Ranked-Play-FAQ#h4q2

> The only restriction on your Ranked group is based on rank. You must be within two tiers of the rest of your team to play in a dynamic group. This means, for example, if you're in Gold, you can only play with those who are in Silver, Gold, or Platinum. Unranked players may play with Bronze, Silver, and Gold players.

Also, I think that your assumption that rank was a solid indicator of personal skill prior to dynamic queue is a bit misguided. Prior to the ranked queueing rank gap restriction, people were being boost simply via duo-queueing. Since the gap restriction, I feel like things may be slightly more accurate, but there are alway loopholes. Very highly ranked players can simply make smurf accounts now that are unranked and boost a Bronze player all the way to Platinum.

**Opinions below**

I think that Riot's intent with this queue is to really force people to start thinking and behaving like a team. It isn't a stretch to say that, historically, in solo queue, there has been a mindset of "I have to carry, I have to do the most damage, I have to have the best score, if I don't carry, we will lose".

This thinking is detrimental to the team dynamic and (IMO) is the source of all the negativity people have for their own teammates. The old queue promotes that 1v9 mentality where a player may feel that it's his effort vs the efforts of everyone else in the game.

Answer (score -1):

***Rank isn't a good indicator of actual skill.***

**Here's why:**

Nowadays, if you can afford it, you can just pay someone to boost your account to whatever elo you desire, there have been [Professional Players](http://2015.na.lolesports.com/articles/competitive-ruling-xian-%E2%80%9Cxiaoweixiao%E2%80%9D-yu) (His ban was actually lifted quite recently) that got banned for providing such services.

A huge ammount of accounts gets banned daily for these reasons.

If you start up a game on a low rank account, i would bet that at least 5 players in that game are smurfs, and if you play ranked on bronze, you will probably be playing agaisnt 1 or 2 Gold + people boosting their friend.

So, in conclusion, rank isn't a good indicator of actual skill most of the times, also people can have off days or they are showing the game to a friend which makes them lose focus and so forth.

Comment: [citation needed]